# Как передать объект из одной формы в другую уже созданную форму? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Это код в форме Start.

```
        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IdleInfo igrok = new IdleInfo()
        {
            money = 5000,
            name = textbox_name_user.Text,
            namecompany = textBox_name_company.Text
        };
        


        this.Close();
        
    }
```

Есть уже созданная форма Form1. Как сделать так что бы из нее можно было работать с этим объектом.

Comment: передавать объект в конструктор Form1

Comment: Если одна из форм создаёт другую, то она должна передать какой-то объект создаваемой. Если обе формы создаются откуда-то из вне, нужно передать обеим формам какой-то объект.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/observer

Comment: Откуда открывается форма Start? Где она создается? Если в главной форме, покажите код.